# Recover Database from Oracle Datafiles

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have datafiles which were recovered from damaged partition. Please help me restore them into a new Oracle database. I'm new to Oracle so this mission is too hard for me. I really need your help!

Comment: More information is needed. What oracle files have have been recovered? If you've recovered only data files of non-system tablespace, then they are useless.

Comment: It's dbf file. Why useless?

Comment: my answer was helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming when you copied these files the database was shutdown.

Backup your all original datafiles somewhere else and copy all your *.dbf files in datafile folder

Give it try to the following commands

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL>

 SQL> startup nomount;
 SQL> alter system set control_files = '/oracle/data/control.dbf';
 SQL> shutdown immediate

SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  264241152 bytes
Fixed Size                  1286916 bytes
Variable Size             205524220 bytes
Database Buffers           54525952 bytes
Redo Buffers                2904064 bytes
Database mounted.

SQL> recover database until cancel;
Media recovery complete.
SQL> alter database open resetlogs;

Database altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: its really pity that OP not responding at all