# How to recover data from Oracle 11g default DBF files after new Installation?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, recovery

I am a very junior developer and got my windows 10 corrupted. I reinstalled the windows and Oracle 11g locally as well but could not find my previous data there. I have the folder and files from the previous installation including all the default DBF files such as CONTROL.DBF, TEMP.DBF, USERS.DBF, SYSAUX.DBF etc etc.

If someone please guide me on how to recover and import data from previous installation to the new one. The data is really important to me.

Comment: check this https://serverfault.com/questions/193839/oracle-database-move-current-server-to-another-machine-problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover Database from Oracle Datafiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435555/recover-database-from-oracle-datafiles)